# How to marshall a list of parts in a SOAP body using Spring-ws

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, spring-ws

I have to write a client for a SOAP webservice in Java. Initially I used wsimport on the wsdl to generate proxy classes and all was well. 
However if there are changes in the wsdl like additions then my proxy classes crashed.

So I tried switching to spring-ws which does not require precompiled stubs.

The soap request should look like this:

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <ws:command>
     <requestName>?</requestName>
     <paramCount>?</paramCount>
     <paramList>
        <item>?</item>
     </paramList>
  </ws:command>
</soapenv:Body>
```

and I am using WebServiceTemplate to send out a request:

```
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate;
webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(url, request);
```

*Here's the question.* How do I manage to tell the spring-ws (or I guess the marshaller) that I simply want a list of elements without any wrapper to be added to the soap body by passing a single object?

**EDIT:**
The body and command are specified in the wsdl and I don't have control over them. What a I have is the *list* of parameters: requestName, paramCount..
This list of parameters is not wrapped in an element like *commandParams* but I have to pass a single parameter to the marshalSendAndReceive() method. If I pass a wrapper element then that element is serialized into the body too violating the webservice contract.

Comment: Could you elaborate on `want a list of elements without any wrapper to be added to the soap body by passing a single object`? may be couple of examples.

Comment: It is static, so you will always need to match the webservice. You can go Restful and use JSON objects, that would be simpler